# Fragment with ListView and details view works too slowly

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I want to implement a layout that has the following design:
List of items on the left, details on the right. This is for tablets and Landscape only.
It works but ListView scroll lags and the whole pattern works incredibly slow. The List has about 20-30 records. All info is textual only. It takes about 1-2s between click and result.
Following is the Layout of fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        style="@style/TransparentBgListView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/gray_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_question"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Question Question Question Question Question Question Question"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/faq_question_textSize" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_question"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_answer"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer Answer "
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/faq_answer_textSize" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I had measured a time in onItemClick between getting corresponding info from data ArrayList and setting textviews texts:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Question item = questionList.get(position);
        Log.i(TAG, "questionList.get(position): "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
        txtQuestion.setText(item.question);
        Log.i(TAG, "txtQuestion.setText(item.question): "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
        txtAnswer.setText(item.answer);
        Log.i(TAG, "txtAnswer.setText(item.answer): "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
    }
```

and its about 20-30ms in total. So why is it works so slowly visually? I was think that its due to using LinearLayout weightSum but changing layout widths by constant value (300dp and 600dp) did not change the overall visual speed.
The following is the adapter (included in fragment code as inner class):

```
private class QuestionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    public QuestionsAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return questionList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        QuestionHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_faq, parent, false);
            holder = new QuestionHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else 
            holder = (QuestionHolder)convertView.getTag();

        Question item = questionList.get(position);

        holder.labelView.setText(item.question);
        FontHelper.setM0FontToViews(holder.labelView);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return questionList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }
}

protected static class QuestionHolder {
    final TextView labelView;
    public QuestionHolder (final View convertView){
        labelView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    }
}
```

the following is what the FontHelper looks like:

```
public class FontsHelper {
    public final static String FONTHELPER_FONTS_PATH = "fonts/";

    public static Typeface getFont(final Context context, final String font) {
        final Typeface mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONTHELPER_FONTS_PATH + font);
        return mFont;
    }

    public static void setFontToView(final TextView view, final String font) {
        final Typeface mFont = getFont(view.getContext(), font);
        if (mFont != null)
            view.setTypeface(mFont);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your adapter code.. I'm going to assume either you're list items are very complex or you aren't properly recycling views

Comment: added it but I doubt its the problem source...

Comment: Is "FontHelper" your own class? Have you tried removing that call to it? Everything else looks fine.

Comment: @Stan have you tried replacing your layout file with a simpler one with just the ListView to check if it's a layout issue?

Comment: I think a bit more of your code would help. Have you profiled it any in the debugger ? (or even entry/exit log messages for your various functions and callbacks) can identify the problems.. (eg what's populating your list that you reference in the adapter, but doesn't appear to be a member of the adapter)

Comment: I have another screen with similar ListView (styled) and this ListView by itself works fine and smooth (no lags, etc). And this ListView has similar with listed adapter with FontHelper using. So I doubt its due to FontHelper

Comment: So I tried to remove FontHelper and it works faster now but still not fast enough. Now I need to make some workaround...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the answer is in comments Im answering my question by myself. The problem was the class-helper FontHelper which loads the corresponding font from assets folder and sets it to given view or views. The class is like:

```
public class FontsHelper {
    public final static String FONTHELPER_FONTS_PATH = "fonts/";

    public static Typeface getFont(final Context context, final String font) {
        final Typeface mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONTHELPER_FONTS_PATH + font);
        return mFont;
    }

    public static void setFontToView(final TextView view, final String font) {
        final Typeface mFont = getFont(view.getContext(), font);
        if (mFont != null)
            view.setTypeface(mFont);
    }
}
```

So the workaround was to load the font once and to keep it in field

```
protected Typeface myFont;
```

and use it in adapter like

```
...
holder.labelView.setText(item.question);
holder.labelView.setTypeFace(myFont);

return convertView;
...
```

finally I made following changes to FontHelper:

```
private static Map<String,Typeface> lastUsedFonts = new HashMap<String,Typeface>();
private static String   lastUsedFontFileName;
private static Typeface lastUsedFont;

public static Typeface getFont(final Context context, final String fontFileName) {

    if ( fontFileName.equals(lastUsedFontFileName) )
        return lastUsedFont;

    if (lastUsedFontFileName != null)
        lastUsedFonts.put(lastUsedFontFileName, lastUsedFont);

    lastUsedFontFileName = fontFileName;
    lastUsedFont = lastUsedFonts.get(fontFileName);

    if (lastUsedFont == null)
        lastUsedFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONTHELPER_FONTS_PATH + fontFileName);

    return lastUsedFont;
}
```

and now there is no need to create field to store the font.